# Compare One Value with Two Columns in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I Have Average Suppose its 38%
Then I have Values in Codeigniter LIke this

```
mark_from   mark_to         Remarks
0                9          Failed
10               19         Also failed
89               99         Excellent
```

I Have used this Query

```
$remarks = $this->db->select('remark')->where('mark_from >=',$average)->where('mark_to <=',$average)->get('remarks')->result_array();
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think out of the box:

```
$this->db->select('remark')
         ->where((int) $average.' BETWEEN mark_from AND mark_to')
         ->get('remarks');
```